# How to change iPhone app name according to language selected?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to change app name according to the user's language preferences?

e.g If English is the language of user's iPhone then app name is "Hello" and if the language is French it would be "Bonjour".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- add a plist file to you project
2- name it InfoPlist.strings
3- make it localized by adding a french language
4- xcode will create two version: one for english and the other for french

open the english vesion and add the line:

CFBundleDisplayName="Hello";

open the french version and add the line

CFBundleDisplayName="Bonjour";

test your application and you will see your app. name chane according to the user local.