# Appstore multiple names

Tags: android, iphone, ios, app-store, google-play

I'm planning on a nice app that will be quite useful, regardless of the country it's used in. That's why I'm already planning on doing it in multiple languages from the beginning. I know you can easily do that with localization and/or other storyboard, but it will also be nice to have the tittle in the corresponding language. If the app is about houses, in english it should be "My home" and in spanish "Mi hogar". Is this possible in the appStore? (I believe not) what about in google Play(Android market)? Would it help to distribute the same app, multiple times, in different languages with the corresponding name, or will this only dilute the downloads and avoid it to become a "trending app"? (I think so) Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: iTunesConnect, the service you use for publishing your app via iTunes, certainly allows multiple (localized) names for the same app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both (App name and change lang in your app) are possible in iOS.

How to change app name:

[How to change iPhone app name according to language selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509888/how-to-change-iphone-app-name-according-to-language-selected)

How to change app content:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly have separate titles (and all listing details) per language for an application in the google play store. When you upload an application to the developer console and click "add language" under listing details you will be able to input the language specific information.